# CSV generates multiple double quote in string of ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I use ruby to generate a CSV file. One of my data is a string which contain a `double quote "`in it, for example `="000123"`.

This is my code:

```
csv = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << ["=\"000123\""]
end
```

However, it will generate a wrong string with additional `double quote`:

```
2.4.0 :005 > puts csv
"=""000123"""
```

What I expect result is `="000123"`. Does anyone know the reason? How to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

That's actually how [CSV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) escapes double quotes:

> 7. If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
>    appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
>    another double quote.  For example:

> ```
>     "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
> ```

and because your field has double quotes inside it, you are required to quote the entire column:

> 5. Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes (however
>    some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes
>    at all).  **If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
>    double quotes may not appear inside the fields.**

(emphasis mine) If you really want to disable that feature though, just set the `quote_char` to something else:

```
puts CSV.generate(quote_char: "'") { |csv| csv << ["=\"000123\""] }
# ="000123"
```

Comment: It looks wrong, but in the 1980s people had a lot of bad ideas about how to escape things, and we're stuck with it now.

Comment: It's not really much worse than double backslashing, "\\t" to show "\t" instead of a tab, just a different character